# How to parse the result of a diff in a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm writing an script that should compare 2 directories and the files inside them and then parse the differences from A.xml to B.xml.

I'm a little lost, can you help me?

```
f_check() {

  diff ${ADIR} ${BDIR}

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then printf "not equal"; else; printf "OK, everything match";fi

}
```

The script should check 2 directories and the files inside if they are equal.

If not it should parse what's different in B from A.

Comment: If you just want to know if files match, use `cmp`, not `diff`. `diff` is much slower because it does the work of figuring out exactly what changed; `cmp` just looks byte-by-byte, and if you tell it you only want an exit status it'll stop the moment it finds a single byte mismatched.

Comment: ...whereas if you *really* need to figure out what's semantically different between two XML files, you want a dedicated special-purpose tool; `diff` isn't part of the appropriate toolkit for that job.

Comment: I want to parse the result of the files if they don't match, not only check if they match

Comment: Right. Again, `diff` is the wrong tool for that job when you want a semantically-meaningful analysis of the difference between two XML files. See f/e http://www.adrianmouat.com/bit-bucket/2009/05/why-use-diffxml/

Comment: Ok , thx. My main problem is that I can only use the default soft in the system.

Comment: Then you'll probably be rolling your own comparison tools in Python (since the language's standard library has some quite good XML tools).

Comment: Great! I'll check that. Thanks for your time Charles.

Comment: You will probably want to use the --recursive flag if there are likely to be subdirectories. I am not clear about the role of these xml files.

Comment: Hi Jon! I don't have any subdirectories.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Comparing a 3GB binary file, `diff -q a b` is about 10-20% faster than `cmp a b`. Tested it multiple times to avoid cache issues. System Openleap 15.

Comment: @Wiimm, use `cmp -s` to get behavior equivalent to `diff -q`. That said, binary files aren't a case the OP has here (`diff` punts on them and doesn't try to calculate a delta at all; it only does the expensive work `cmp` doesn't on text files... like the OP's XML content -- and then when not passed `-q`).

Answer (score 0):

compare two directories:

diff -qr dir1 dir2